# How to find the GeoPoint coordinates of a city for an Android app

Tags: android, geolocation

How do I find the GeoPoint locations for various cities around the world.
I am trying to load a map on my android app with certain cities having a pin overlay item.

I was following the example on Google's android tutorials where they mention locations for Mexico City and japan. How about the other cities around the world.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using Geocoder. Specifically [`Geocoder.getFromLocationName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Once you get the List of [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html)es you can get the latitude and longitude from those Addresses.